# Foundation 6 dropdown menu with input element

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to have input in dropdown menu in founation, but once input is clicked, whole menu hides, how can I achieve such behaviour?
This is codepen of one of original examples, with just input added:

```
<input />
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqyroK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you can change this line:

`<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>`

To this:

`<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu data-close-on-click-inside="false">`

An explanation of all dropdown plugin options can be found **[here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html#js-options)**.

Comment: Yeah that did it!